# Is it possible to use an overlay scrollbar with vue-virtual-scroller?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, scrollbar

I am using vue-virtual-scroller and I want to remove the space reserved for the scrollbar and make it an overlay scrollbar. Has anyone done this?

I have tried using vue3-perfect-scrollbar, but it didn't work properly in conjunction with vue-virtual-scroller.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.